# Trouble passing variable in terraform apply

Tags: terraform

I am using Terraform Cloud for my Backend with version 1.1

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
  cloud {
    hostname     = "app.terraform.io"
    organization = "MyOrg"

    workspaces {
      name = "MyWorkspace"
    }
  }
}
```

I have a variable in my HCL

```
variable "app_version" {
  description = "The application version to deploy"
  type        = string
}
```

I am attempting to set it when I call `terraform apply` like so:-

```
terraform apply -var="app_version=v0.0.1"
```

I get the following error though.

```sh
1 error occurred:
        * Invalid HCL in variable "app_version": At 1:15: Unknown token: 1:15 IDENT v0.0.1
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Terraform docs for command line variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html#input-variables-on-the-command-line) do a poor job of explaining that, but you basically need to wrap the value in double quotes. As the value passed after `=` is interpreted as Terraform expression, not constant (which opens up for other possibilities).

So, try:

```
terraform apply -var 'app_version="v0.0.1"'
```

Also notice there should be no `=` after `-var`

Comment: Thanks for you advice. However, that has the exact same outome.

Answer (score 0):

Grzegorz was correct but if you are on a windows machine you will need to escape the double quotes but adding a \ before each double quote.